# Joint js link circle and triangle shapes

Tags: javascript, jointjs

i need to create some links in Joint JS that start with a circle source and end with a triangle or viceversa, got this but it doesn work :

```
var link1 = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect1.id },
    target: { id: rect3.id },
    attrs: {
        '.connection': { 'stroke-width': 20 },
        '.marker-source': { d: 'M 0 0 5 0 5 20 0 20 z', fill: '#232E78' },
        '.marker-target': { d: 'M 0 0 5 0 5 20 0 20 z', fill: '#232E78' }
    }
});
```

Any idea ?, thanks in advance !

Comment: You have the right approach, but the markup you are using for the `marker-source` and `marker-target` defines a rectangle, not a circle or triangle. Are you asking how to define these shapes in SVG?

Comment: Exactly ! @MikeGoodwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. You can play around with the paths to size it how you want:

```
var link1 = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect1.id },
    target: { id: rect3.id },
    attrs:           attrs: {
      '.connection': { 'stroke-width': 2 },
      '.marker-source': { d: 'M 0 0 a 5 5 0 1 0 0 1', 'stroke-width': 0, fill: '#232E78' },
      '.marker-target': { d: 'M 10 -5 10 5 0 0 z', 'stroke-width': 0, fill: '#232E78' }
            }
});
```

For the full detail, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhm35Lh8/3/)

The end result looks like this:

[image: Circle triangle link]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike, i don't know why i got two triangles at each side when i use your code, in  fiddle works fine, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var link1 = new joint.dia.Link({
    source: { id: rect1.id }, target: { id: rect3.id },
    vertices: [{ x: 400, y: 250 }],
    attrs: {'.connection': { stroke: '#7c68fc', 'stroke-width': 20 },
    '.marker-source': { fill: '#232E78', stroke: '#4b4a67', d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z'},
        '.marker-target': { fill: '#232E78', stroke: '#4b4a67', d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' } 
}      
});
```

Comment: Care for any explanation? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Please, read the best practices, on how to make [a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and please, update the answer with explanations. Thank you.